# How deploy WARs one after other by script after startup wildfly?

Tags: deployment, wildfly, war

I have problem with starting Wildfly. I have more than 40 WARs on application server and XMX limitation. Sometimes server will start, sometimes not... 
There is any apportunity to deploy WARs one after other after startup Wildfly?
Server has problem with start when is deploying all WARs during starting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regardless how you deploy, you can deploy one-by-one.

If you deploy by copying your WARs to `standalone/deployments`, then yes, you can (1) start an empty server and then (2) copy the wars one-by-one manually or using a shell script. However, it is quite possible that your problem will re-appear when you shut down and start up the fully deployed server again. To solve that, maybe you could have a script to undeploy the WARs before shutting the server down.

You can reach a similar effect also using `jboss-cli`: (1) start an empty server (2) connect your cli client `jboss-cli.sh --connect` and (3) deploy the WARs one-by-one: `deploy ~/Desktop/my-app1.war` ... See https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Admin_Guide.html#standalone-server-3

Comment: Thx for answer, but I know this solution and I am not satisfied with this approach. 
Maybe you know, how deploy WAR (micro service) on demand? For example: one service is listening for JMS events, which will have information what application I need to deploy before send to it some REST event

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for Serverless architecture.