# How to limit current deployments in Wildfly11

Tags: deployment, wildfly, wildfly-11

I have a problem with wildfly11. I've got about 240 artifacts to deploy at server starts. Is there any possibility to limit current deployments to i.e. 10 artifacts.

I mean when I copy all of the artifacts, then wildfly will scan all of them and starts deploy max 10 of them at one time?

Eventually is there a possibility to not redeploy artifacts after server restart?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018327/how-deploy-wars-one-after-other-by-script-after-startup-wildfly

Answer (score 0):

One solution is not to use the scanner for this and deploy your deployments with a jboss-cli script or just to mark those deployments with .skipdeploy and remove those marker files